# GCP Load Balancer: cannot delete "match all" under "Host and path rules"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-http-load-balancer

I'm trying to configure a Google Cloud load balancer to forward API request to a backend service and all other requests to a storage bucket. However, *all* requests are directed to the storage bucket. This seems to be because I can't delete the entry in **Host and path rules** with host `*` and path `/*`.

The current setting for **Host and path rules** looks as follows: [image: Current "Host and path rules" setting]

To me this looks like all requests will match against host `*` and path `/*` and be forwarded to `bucket-cmd-com` (before matching against the entries for `web-api-backend`), and this is exactly what I experience (a request against e.g. `/calc/unfinished/count` results in a Google 404 page).

On the **Load balancer details** page, if I click **EDIT**, go to **Host and path rules** and click the **X** to the right of the entry for `host=*, path=/*`, the entry disappears from the list. However, after I save this (by clicking **Update**) the entry is still there.

How do I either delete this "match all" entry for `bucket-cmd-com` or make it work in some other way?

Comment: Is your issue resolved?if yes, can you post the procedure you've followed as Solution and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/url-map#adding_a_url_map) it states:

> "A newly created URL map matches only one path, the default one (/*).
> This default path matcher is created automatically. All traffic that
> does not match a manually created path matcher or host rule is sent to
> the URL map default backend service."

Therefore, as it is a default configuration can not be removed. Per my understanding looks like the settings `host=*`, and `path=/*` are configured during load balancer creation, similar to the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IA21w.png).

I think the best way to achieve this configuration would be specifying as needed during Load Balancer configuration the Host and path rules based on your application needs.

Additional information can be found on this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/url-map-concepts).

Comment: Any update on this @runeks? Kindly advise/upvote if this resolved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The following configuration works as expected, ie. directing requests to `/api/*` to `web-api-backend-2` and everything else to the `bucket-cmd-com` bucket. Note that the "match all" rule (`/*`) appears *after* the `/api/*` rule.

[image: GCP Load Balancer "Host and path rules" configuration]